# App Review Rejected: Use 'Setup Apple Pay' Image Button

Tags: ios, applepay

My app review got rejected by Apple:

> Specifically, Buy with Apple Pay button showing without Apple Pay set up.
>
> Next Steps:
>   When Apple Pay is not enabled on a user's device the user should see Set up Apple Pay Button.
>
> Resources: For guidance on how to use Apple Pay button assets and payment marks in the customer purchase flow, see the [Apple Pay Button and Resources](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/).

But what I can download from that page is the 'Apple Pay' button images, NO 'Setup Apple Pay' button image is included at all!

All I could find is a raw image from [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/technologies/apple-pay/)

[image: setupApplePay]

However, this does not come with a resouce pack and dimention/ratio does not go well with other 'Apple Pay' buttons.
What the hack Apple...

Am I missing something here? Anyone knows where to download the 'Setup Apple Pay' button images set? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the PassKit framework to your project and import it into your corresponding view controller/s. PassKit has a PKPaymentButton that "returns a button instance with the Apple Pay Logo".

You can use the documentation to setup the corresponding functionality. It should be pretty straight forward, but let me know if you have questions. I hope this helps!

**iOS**

*PKPaymentButton*: https://developer.apple.com/reference/passkit/pkpaymentbutton

*PassKit*: https://developer.apple.com/reference/passkit

**Safari**

For the web, you will use **Apple Pay JS**. From there, you will use the **ApplePaySession** class to handle payments. Within the ApplePaySession class, you will see documentation on how to display different Apple Pay buttons using HTML and CSS. You can also use **openPaymentSetup** to display a setup Apple Pay button.

*Apple Pay JS*: https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs

*ApplePaySession*: https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs/applepaysession

*openPaymentSetup*: https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs/applepaysession/2710269-openpaymentsetup

Read the documentation and it should all be right there. Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But unfortunately I am developing a hybrid app which is based on HTML5, Javascript and CSS. Therefore I can't have direct access to PassKit. If you were developing Apple Pay on Safari, we should have a Setup Apple Pay button on our webpage. Don't we?

Comment: @nigong I updated my answer to include using Apple Pay on a web page. I hope that helps!

Comment: I donot see the "Setup Apple Pay" button when i have not configured my credit card. I use self.btnApplePay = [self.btnApplePay initWithPaymentButtonType:PKPaymentButtonTypeSetUp paymentButtonStyle:PKPaymentButtonStyleWhiteOutline]; to display. self.btnApplePay is of type PKPaymentButton created in the storyboard and connected through IBOutlet.

Comment: @user3353890 I have created a button in my button and set its type to PKPaymentButton. In my viewDidLoad it doesnt let me initialize it with the init function like mentioned in the documention ps i also tried making an instance of the button in my VC like var payment: PKPaymentButton! it still doesnt let me call the init function. how can it be done in swift?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS for the "Set up (Apple) Pay" button can be found here in the documentation for the `ApplePaySession.openPaymentSetup` function:  https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs/applepaysession/2710269-openpaymentsetup