# How to show "Set Up apple pay" button when userCanPay(PayProvider.apple_pay) returns false

Tags: ios, flutter, applepay

I am using flutter's [Pay](https://pub.dev/packages/pay) plugin to integrate apple pay.

It works fine on emulator, but on real device, it does not show apple pay button. I have completed all of the configuration steps.

When i debug the code, the `userCanPay(PayProvider.apple_pay)` method is returning false, as i have not setup apple pay on my account, that's why userCanPay is returning false.

So its just showing `Stripe` payment, and not apple pay button on the real device.

I believe apple will reject the app.

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874069/app-review-rejected-use-setup-apple-pay-image-button), where someone reported about "Set up apple pay"

I need to know if i need to create a custom button for `"Set Up apple pay"`, or does `Pay` library provide something for it, and do i need to write code on swift for redirection to the add payment method view.

```
_payClient = Pay({
  PayProvider.google_pay: PaymentConfiguration.fromJsonString(
      defaultGooglePay),
  PayProvider.apple_pay: PaymentConfiguration.fromJsonString(
      defaultApplePay),
});

Future <void> _checkIfApplePayInstalled() async {
  if(_payClient!=null) {
    _hasApplePay = await _payClient!.userCanPay(PayProvider.apple_pay);

    if (_hasApplePay) {
      setState(() {
        // Write here your code..
      });
      print('Apple Pay is available on this device!');
    } else {
      print('Apple Pay is not available on this device!');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would apple reject your app for doing the right thing?  If the user hasn't set up Apple Pay on their device then you don't show Apple Pay as an option. You don't need to show a "set up Apple Pay" button. Now, if you are using Stripe/Apple Pay when you should be using in app purchase you will be rejected. Stripe and Apple Pay can only be used for purchasing real world goods and services, not for digital goods and services delivered in your app.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know that i need to use in-app purchase instead of apple pay.